# Android: в приложении ... произошла ошибка. Где посмотреть логи в телефоне?

Tags: android, логирование

Всем доброго времени суток. В моём приложении иногда при запуске `Activity` вылетает ошибка:

> В приложении ... произошла ошибка

Если я запускаю его на эмуляторе на компьютере, то никакой ошибки не вылетает. Есть ли возможность посмотреть системные логи в телефоне, чтобы понять, в чём заключается ошибка? Root права, если что есть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подключите свой телефон, запустите на нем приложение. В Android Studio в вкладке android monitor выберите свой телефон в подключенных устройства, а затем выберите system в списке приложений для дебага.

Comment: А если Eclipse?

Comment: Тоже самое. Там где отображаются логи с вашего эмулятора есть поле для переключения между устройствами. И для переключения отслеживаемого приложения.